# Dollar symbol not getting summed in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to manage my expenses using a google spreadsheet. The problem is that I use dollars and euros. I write the numbers like $23 and €25. The sum function works properly for the euro symbol, but it returns zero for the $ sign.

I set up a small example here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_mg6xxsae2ybDHXQAqGLddXmJMDsYaaGkkhRY2YIIQc/edit#gid=0

Both columns has the same sum function, but only one works. Why?

Thanks in advance.

---EDIT:
I updated the example with some data of the real world. And I changed the timezone of the spreadsheet to the one that corresponds to me (spain). I highlighted two examples in the sheet2. As you can see, the examples are using the correct currency format, but the sum stills zero. The same configuration in the sheet1 works nicely.

I'm starting to think the problem is the timezone of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Rather than use the comma as your decimal separator, have you tried using the period, formatting like $xx.xx instead?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hi8DDafrej7544mVEj1e4iEI-j6n6Vu2LttYaDYurOg/edit?usp=sharing

The same addition works for the sheet above.

I formatted column A it as Currency $ and Column C as Currency British Pound (There is an option when you click at Format to add more currency and there you can pick Pounds). Looks like the addition works in this case.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect that the currency is not the problem. Thanks

Comment: Dead link, please add a working URL

Answer (score 0):

$ is a character used in formulas to anchor row or column references. Try writing the number without symbols at all, and instead set the format accordingly instead.

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14.3

Comment: Dead link, please add a working URL